# how to include addEventListener in content script in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My content script is not working on certain tab updation event ,I have tried every possible thing but i want to run the script on DOMcontent loaded event in content script by using line of code

```
    window.addEventListener("DOMFocusIn", function(e) {
    }
```

or also have used code

```
  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    }
```

but it is not working. Anybody help please.

Comment: I have a strong feeling mano again refers to dynamically changing DOM (through AJAX) as _"tab updation"_ (as is the case in **[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379473/content-script-is-not-working-in-chrome-extension)**). Again, `DOMContentLoading` won't get triggered in the case of dynamic DOM changes, but (as already explained in my answer to the aforementioned question) you should use a `MutationObserver`.

Answer (score 1):

I think DOMContentLoaded won't be called again when the page updates. If you want to monitor changes to your content, you might want to use:

```
$("#someDiv").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    alert("tree changed");
});
```